# How to add same layer object to any 'UITextField'

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
//setting underline to the bottom of the textfield
        CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
CGFloat borderWidth = 2;
border.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
border.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.email
                          .frame.size.height - borderWidth,    self.email.frame.size.width, self.email.frame.size.height);
border.borderWidth = borderWidth;

    [self.email.layer addSublayer:border];
    self.email.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [self.password.layer addSublayer:border];
    self.password.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [self.confirmPassword.layer addSublayer:border];
    self.password.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    }
```

i want to use the same border object for my every textfield but it is taking only last sublayer at a time. How can i add the same layer to all textfields without creating more instance of CALayer??

Comment: You can't add the same layer to multiple layers (otherwise, the `superlayer` property wouldn't make sense). When you add a layer to another layer, it is implicitly removed from its previous `superlayer` (parent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One layer cannot be in two places at once, any more than *you* can be in two places at once; a layer can be a sublayer of only one layer. So you need to do this repeatedly, making a *different* CALayer, for every text field.

The easy way to code that in one place is: Subclass UITextField to add the layer to itself and manage its size, and use instances of your subclass throughout the app.

Comment: @omz thanks for the edit: you can see from the error that I was thinking ahead to my second paragraph before I'd written it :)

Comment: OP, take note of what I say in that answer about the size. You don't get autoresizing of sublayers in iOS, so if, say, your text fields change size when the app rotates or for any other reason after you initially create the layer, you'll be in trouble later unless you add code to resize the sublayer manually.

Comment: @vishwasparashar Now you're leeching. Don't do that. I think I answered correctly the question _that you asked_, i.e. why your code wasn't working. If you have a new question, ask it as a new _question_ — don't try to drag things out in the comments.

Comment: @vishwasparashar No problem! I'll watch for your new question.